# EF code first from database relationship

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and EF but I really want to get it.

I am using Entity Framework with a code-first approach and an existing database.

I have a database like this (is a smart version):

[Database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP9Uu.png)

I want to load table for view like this :

```
Header(Orders)
--------------------------------------------------------------
Question   | Question.AttrName        | Question.Attrname2      |...
----------- 
Item.name | Answer.ValueForAttrname| Answer.ValueForAttrname2| 
....
Item.NameN| Value                    | Value                    |
```

Only for show, saving by stored procedure.

In my real database I don't have any FK, and I can't change database, but I can `Create View` for this.

What relationship I'm need in Fluent.api?

Please, knock me in right way

PS. Full diagram of the database looks like this (but this does not have FK):

[Full Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V76c.png)

Comment: What do you mean by *I want to load table for view like this*. You want to read data from a view in your database? Views don't have FK, so you can't create relationship between your entities by using views, nor by using tables without FK. Did I miss something?

Comment: sorry for dirty question.
Yes, i am read data from views, and all keys I  am defination in Fluent.api
and this work

Comment: Actually it looks views can have association (though I've never done it myself), I'm not sure. Can you share the code you tried?

Comment: Sorry, this question about code arhitecture, what classes i am need?
some like  class ds_order{ int orid...list<Question> question>
and  class question { orid int, iid int, List<Answer> answers }
class Answer{ orid int, iid int, Attrid, Value}
or some like this?